# Удаление child с Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

```
data.child("Users_database").child(user.getUid()).setValue(null);
```

Я пробовал так сделать, но не помогло. Есть ли другие варианты удаления `child` 
`removeValue()` пытался и так, не получается. `removeValue()` значение какого-либо `child` удаляет, но сам `сhild` и то, что внутри этого не умеет удалять

[image: Нужно удалить весь с]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `data.child("Users_database").child(user.getUid()).removeValue();`

update:
в документации вот так выглядит код:

> `firebase.child(id).removeValue();`